# Is QProcess::finished emitted if the child process crashes?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess, qt-signals

The documentation says that the `error()` signal will be emitted if the child process crashes, but would `finished()` be emitted as well or is it only emitted when it exits successfully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. And it returns you status, as [docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qprocess.html#ExitStatus-enum) state:

```
void QProcess::finished ( int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus ) [signal]

QProcess::NormalExit    0   The process exited normally.
QProcess::CrashExit 1   The process crashed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out by testing it. Write a small program that does a NULL pointer dereference (this will guarantee a crash):

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    Foo* foo = 0;
    int d = foo->a;
}
```

Make sure you build without optimization so that the dereference doesn't get optimized out. Then run it in a QProcess and check whether `finished()` is being emitted.

Comment: No. It is not true. Qt is crossplatform library. If it works in some way on a particular system, does not mean it will work same on other system in general.

Comment: @Lol4t0 I'm not sure what you mean with "not true." The test will make it clear, without a doubt, whether or not QProcess emits the signal. In your answer, you found the actual documentation that clears it up. Here, I simply provided a way to get some empirical evidence. The assumption of course is that if the signal is emitted on the OP's platform, then the same holds true for all supported platforms. Assumptions aren't that great though, so obviously your answer is the better one :)

Comment: Assumptions are bad first of all because `QProcess` is _platfrom dependednt_ part of Qt. You said that 'You can find out by testing it'. But you _can't_ actually. You _can only assume_

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is, as other have noted, "Yes."

And that feels like a problem to me because without a reference to the object that emitted the signals you have to do something like:

```
void on_finished( int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus )
{
    if ( existStatus == QProcess::CrashExit )
    {
        // We'll handle in on_errorOccured()
        return;
    }

    // ...
}


void on_errorOccured( QProcess::ProcessError error )
{
    // ...
}
```

As an alternate to accepting I wrote a thin wrapper class that connects (only!) to `QProcess::stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState newState)` and works out what happened using `newState` and calling the `QProcess` object:

```
void ProcessWrapper::on_stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState newState)
{
    switch (newState)
    {
    case QProcess::Starting:
        // No action needed
        break;
    case QProcess::Running:
        emit( started( this ) );
        break;
    case QProcess::NotRunning:
        if ( m_process.exitStatus() != QProcess::NormalExit )
            emit( crashed( this, m_process.error() ) );
        else
            emit( finished( this, m_process.exitCode() ) );
        break;
    }
}
```

The signals the wrapper emits have two properties:

- Only one signal is emitted when a process ends, and which one tells you how it ended (normally or abnormally).
- Each signal includes both a code for how things did and a pointer to the object so that the user can inquire further.