# How to start a few QProcess in parallel and block until all of them have exited?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to start a few `QProcess` in parallel, and block until all of them have exited.

I'm thinking of putting each `QProcess*` in a vector, and connect the `finished()` signal to a counter. The main thread busy waits until the counter reaches size of the vector.

However, I'm concerned that the counter may not be thread safe, and it's not terribly efficient.

Comment: The counter will be thread safe if you only increment the counter in the main thread. Remember cross thread signals are queued. Also like Amartel said make sure the process actually started to avoid waiting forever.

Comment: I would use signals and slots instead of busy waiting or is your main application a non gui application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you connect all of the finished() signals to a single object living in the main thread, you don't need to worry about protecting the counter. Each signal will get queued and processed in turn in the main thread. Just make sure you use a [Qt::QueuedConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) when you connect.

Amartel is correct about checking to make sure they launch before letting them run.

**Edit:**
As mentioned here ([Is QProcess::finished emitted when process crashes in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991509/is-qprocessfinished-emitted-when-process-crashes-in-qt)), you might consider connecting to the error() signal as well.

Also, consider [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrent.html). It was designed for this express purpose.

Comment: I guess, handling `QProcess::started()` signal will also do the trick.

Comment: True. With signals and slots, there's really no waiting required at all. I'm not even sure that storing the QProcess in a QVector is required, since the receiver of the signal can use QObject::sender() to destroy the QProcess when finished.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely protect the counter with `QMutex`.

And I don't see any problem with efficiency. What are you afraid of?

Though there is one hidden potential problem - a process may not emit `finished()` signal. For example, if it could not start - it will emit `QProcess::error()` with `QProcess::FailedToStart` code, and if it crashed - it will emit error with `QProcess::Crashed` code. In both cases your thread will wait for eternity.

Comment: Checking for a successful start is a good idea. It will still emit finished() if it crashed, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991509/is-qprocessfinished-emitted-when-process-crashes-in-qt

Comment: I don't like busy waiting in general. The processes that I want to start generally takes a few minutes each, and busy waiting basically robs a CPU core that could be used for other things. I guess I could call qSleep() but in general I'm looking for a wait/notify mechanism

Comment: Well, that is what `QThread::exec()` for. The thread will sleep, until a signal is emitted. BTW, a little article about correct usage of QThread: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ P.S.: Phlucious's answer is much better.